# How can I get information about my acceleration method?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, ati, radeon

I created a file at  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf` to change my acceleration method to EXA to prevent a problem I've been experiencing. The problem is, from time to time, all the windows go all black, and even if I try to restart those applications, they start back as all black windows. My graphic card is ATI Mobility Radeon X300 on a IBM T43 machine using xf86-video-ati open source driver. File I created contains the following code:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "AccelMethod" "EXA"
EndSection
```

According to [this](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) page, R300 family doesn't support glamor, it instead supports EXA. That seemed to me as a possible solution as to change AccelMethod, but the problem is still there. And I am not even sure whether the change I made actually affected something or not. How can I learn which AccelMethod I currently use?